# I can't able do Vagrant up in git bash getting plenty of times same error

Tags: vagrant-windows

Error - internal:dir:97:'open':wrong number of arguments(given 2, expected 1)(ArgumentError)

from C:/Users/Welcome/.vagrant.d/gems/3.1.3/gems/rubyhacks-0.1.5/lib/rubyhacks.rb:690:in `entries'

from C:/Users/Welcome/.vagrant.d/gems/3.1.3/gems/rubyhacks-0.1.5/lib/rubyhacks.rb:690:in `entries'